# Passing variables through callback function in GTK C

Tags: c, function, callback, gtk

I'm trying to print the value of the variable `i` on the console from my callback
functon, but instead of printing 23 it keeps printing some address 11652528 etc...

I've been searching quite a lot on the net and according to an old GTK tutorial (where the actual `G_CALLBACK` Macro was `GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC`) this should work.

Does anyone have an idea where the error is??

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

void f_window(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("%d\n",GPOINTER_TO_INT(data));
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gint i=23;

    GtkWidget * MainWindow = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    MainWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(MainWindow),"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(f_window),GINT_TO_POINTER(i));

    gtk_widget_show_all(MainWindow);
    gtk_main();


    gtk_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If my answer helped, consider clicking the big tick next to the vote score to accept it. Good luck, and bravo for using C and GTK.

Answer (score 6):

The `"delete-event"` signal callback takes [**three**](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) arguments.

The function signature for `f_window` should be `GtkWidget* widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data`.

You are actually printing the value of `event` in your code.